# Apps Script send Gmail attachment to external API using getBytes()

Tags: google-apps-script, email-attachments

I'm trying to create a Gmail add-on using Apps Script. This calls a third-party web API created in C# to post the email content to another system.

The API method uses POST, and accepts JSON formatted data in the body as parameter.

I can now post messages without attachments.

I there is a parameter for attachments in the method, defined as:
public byte[] paramName {get; set;}.

I thought that I can use the getBytes() method, and send its return as parameter to the method.

Code snippet:

```
var attachments = message.getAttachments();
  var lists = [];
  for(var i = 0; i < attachments.length; i++){
    var attachment = {
      "Id": id,
      "FileByte": attachments[i].getBytes(),
      "FileName": attachments[i].getName()
    }
    
    lists.push(attachment);

  }

  var data = {
    "Email": email,
    "Comment" : byteMsg,
    "Id": id,
    "List": lists, // attachments here
    "Type": type
  }
  
  var url = urlAPI
    var options = {
    method: 'post',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    muteHttpExceptions: true,
    headers: header,
    payload: JSON.stringify(data)
  };
```

Inspecting the logs shows the data (truncated due to length):
Logging output too large. Truncating output. [-119.0, 80.0, 78.0, 71.0, 13.0, 10.0, 26.0, 10.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 13.0, 73.0, 72.0, 68.0, 82.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -56.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -6.0, 8.0, 6.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -28.0, -22.0, 8.0, 56.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 9.0, 112.0, 72.0, 89.0, 115.0, 0.0, 0.0, 18.0, 116.0,...

There are negative values which I'm not sure if they are valid.

I get an 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object' error. Which was similar to the error I was getting with Comment parameter above (also a byte[]) when I was figuring out how it works.

Has anyone made something or exactly like this? Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: By guessing your issue from your question, I proposed a modification point as an answer. Could you please confirm it? But, unfortunately, I cannot know the specification of the API you want to use. I apologize for this. So if the request is not correct, please provide detailed information on the specification of the API you want to use? By this, I would like to confirm it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your following situation in your question,

> Inspecting the logs shows the data (truncated due to length): Logging output too large. Truncating output. [-119.0, 80.0, 78.0, 71.0, 13.0, 10.0, 26.0, 10.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 13.0, 73.0, 72.0, 68.0, 82.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -56.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -6.0, 8.0, 6.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -28.0, -22.0, 8.0, 56.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 9.0, 112.0, 72.0, 89.0, 115.0, 0.0, 0.0, 18.0, 116.0,...

> There are negative values which I'm not sure if they are valid.

I thought that in your situation, you might be required to use the unit8array. When the byte array is retrieved from the blob using Google Apps Script, it's the int8array. In order to convert from the int8array to the unit8array, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
"FileByte": attachments[i].getBytes(),
```

#### To:

```
"FileByte": Uint8Array.from(attachments[i].getBytes()),
```

#### References:

- [getBytes() of Class Blob](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/blob#getBytes())
- [Uint8Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Uint8Array)

Comment: Thank Tanaike.

I tried converting to Uint8Array as you suggested, but the results are the same. There are still negative values, it looks like they were copied as is.

I did try the code snippet below, and this works. I'm not sure if getBytes() return the same thing.
var b = [-119.0, 80.0, 78.0, 71.0, 13.0, 10.0, 26.0, 10.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 13.0, 73.0, 72.0, 68.0, 82.0, -56.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -6.0];
  console.log(b);
  var u = Uint8Array.from(b);
  console.log(u)

Comment: @Paul Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. From `I tried converting to Uint8Array as you suggested, but the results are the same.`, unfortunately, I cannot understand your current situation. Because when I tested my proposed script, I confirmed that the int8array is converted to the unit8array. But, I would like to support you. So can you provide the detailed flow for replicating your issue of `I'm not sure if getBytes() return the same thing.`? By this, I would like to confirm it.

Comment: @Paul For example, when `"FileByte": Uint8Array.from([...attachments[i].getBytes()]),` is used, what result will you obtain? If this was not the direct solution to your issue, can you provide the detailed information for correctly replicating your issue? By this, I would like to confirm it.

Comment: no need to apologize, I appreciate your help. I have tested your code on using a small Apps Script function and it works. For some reason it does not work on the Gmail add-on.  However your reply gave me an idea and found a solution (sorry I forgot to copy where saw it) by using this code: var att = attachments[i].getBytes();

    var file = [];

    for(var x = 0; x < att.length; x++){
      file.push(att[x] & 0xFF);
    }

Comment: I'm marking this answer as the solution as while the exact code does not work (in Gmail add-on in my code at least), the idea is correct.

Comment: @Paul Thank you for replying and adding the information. From `I have tested your code on using a small Apps Script function and it works. For some reason it does not work on the Gmail add-on.`, `Uint8Array.from()` uses V8 runtime. Is this related to your current issue? For example, from your provided script, I thought that when `var file = attachments[i].getBytes().map(b => b & 0xFF)` cannot be used, V8 runtime might be the reason of this issue.

Comment: I'm using V8 runtime. I don't know why Uint8Array.from() returns exactly the same values as the source array. Thanks again!